# Zipping / Encryption on Solaris 10

Tags: linux, unix, encryption, solaris, solaris-10

I have a dump file which I am zipping it up -> sending it over a network -> and burning it onto DVD.

However, now i would require encryption AES 256 on the dump file. I am running Solaris 10. Is there any equivalent like WINZIP whereby i can do encryption and zip at the same time ?

If not, encryption on the dump file will do, i can zip it up later.

Please advise.

Regards, Noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the encrypt command to encrypt your dump file:

```
$ encrypt -a aes  [-i input-file] [-o output-file]
```

you can use `encrypt -l` to see possible encryptions and keysizes.

Comment: can i check the aes is using 128 or 256 bit encryption ?

Comment: you can use `encrypt -l` to see the keysize possible